# Use Laravel 4 Auth with custom table name

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I am creating a new laravel 4 backend based on an existing database. I have then a table named 'FormMembers' that contains email and passwords for my members.

I would like to use Auth:: functions like :

```
$credentials = array(
    'sEmail' => Input::get('email'),
    'sPassword' => Input::get('password')
);

if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
    return Response::json(Auth::user());
} else {
    return Response::json(array('flash' => 'invalid password or email.'), 500);
}
```

So I changed the table field in **auth.php** from 'users' to 'FormMembers' and did the same to the Users model. But when calling Auth::user() I got the error :

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Undefined index: password","file":"\/home\/www\/accred\/web\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Auth\/EloquentUserProvider.php","line":75}}
```

Do you have any idea how I could manage it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eloquent [user provider requires](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php#L75) a `password` field in the credentials array. You passed an array with the key `sPassword`.

You should be able to do

```
$credentials = array(
    'password' => Input::get('email'),
    'sEmail' => Input::get('password'),
);

Auth::attempt($credentials);
```

And handle the rest from the User eloquent model. Even if your user table has different columns.

EDIT:
The Auth::attempt() function get's handled by the Illuminate's [Guard](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php) class.
This calls the `retrieveByCredentials` and then the `validateCredentials` method of the class that implements the `UserProviderInterface`. By default this is the `EloquentUserProvider`.

The `retrieveByCredentials` method uses all except the password-containing keys of your credentials array. It returns one User eloquent model object. So use 
your 'sEmail' key there.

The `validateCredentials` method that get's called on the eloquent user provider checks if the hash of the `password` field in the credentials array matches with the hashed password retrieved from the `getAuthPassword` method on your User object, wich it needs to implement, as it implements the `UserInterface`.

So, you should overwrite the `getAuthPassword` method on your User class.

```
public function getAuthPassword(
{
    return $this->sPassword;
}
```

Like this it returns the hashed password stored in the DB.

Ofcourse your passwords should be hashed in the same way as Hash::make does. If not:

1. Let all your users reset their password
2. reimplement the [`BcryptHasher`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Hashing/BcryptHasher.php)

Comment: Sorry I am new to laravel, could you develop your answer on how to handle in my User eloquent model the fact that I have different columns names?

Comment: With your sample of code I got : `{"error":{"type":"Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException","message":"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `FormMembers` where `email` = alex@alex.com limit 1)","file":"\/home\/www\/accred\/web\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Connection.php","line":539}}`

Comment: I edited the answer with a whole bunch of explanation. Give it a try.

Comment: Badly this doesn't change the SQL error, still getting the email unknown error...

Comment: What does the credentials array look like? You need a `password` field and a `sEmail` field.

Comment: It seems to work indeed :) . Now I have got an error because my password is wrong but I guess it's because of the hash as you explained. Thank you !