# Laravel 4 change User email and password

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I have a database with columns **sEmail** and **sPassword**. But I need to call :

```
Auth::attempt(Input::only('email', 'password')
```

in order to log in my user. So I get a SQL Exception because **email** and **password** doesnt exists in my table...

I can't change my columns names, so how is it possible to solve my problem?

Answer (score -1):

Laravel should know that you are using different column names, you should change your code to

```
$email = $input['email'];
$password = $input['password']; 
Auth::attempt(array('sEmail' => $email, 'sPassword' => $password));
```

Comment: No laravel doesn't know it... cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983504/use-laravel-4-auth-with-custom-table-name

Comment: you are right, but did you change the function getAuthPassword() in your user model

Comment: I needed to do it indeed.